# RN Listview taking each character as a row of given json string

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, listview, react-native

I have used Listview in other projects and just copied the code from there but now having an issue which I am not getting how to tackle.

I am having the following json got from my server and stored in my session class which I am using as a data source, But the render row does not take objects as a row item instead taking each character as a new row item , whic i have checked during debugging. using the following  code,any help is appreciated

JSON

```
[{"id":1,"name":null,"fullName":"Behraj Khan "},{"id":2,"name":null,"fullName":"Fareeha "},{"id":3,"name":null,"fullName":"Kashif "}]
```

Code

```
 constructor(props) {
          super(props);

            const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
            var facultyMembers;
            if(SessionManager.getSessionValue(Constants.FACULTY_MEMBERS) !== null){
                facultyMembers = SessionManager.getSessionValue(Constants.FACULTY_MEMBERS);
            }
            this.state = {
                 dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(facultyMembers)
              };
          }


 render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ListView
                    style={styles.listviewcontainer}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={(row) => this.renderRow(row)}
                    renderHeader={this.state.showHeader ? () => this.renderHeader(this.state.headerText) : () => {
                    }}
                    renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator}/>}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

renderRow = (rowData) => (
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='gainsboro' onPress={() => {
            this.state.onPress(rowData)
        }}>
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text style={styles.header}>
                    {rowData.fullName}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
```

In first iteration of renderRow i got `[`
in second i got `{` 
in third i got `"` and so on
[image][image]

Comment: Passing a string to `cloneWithRows` will cause that problem.  Are you sure that you parsed the JSON response from the server?

Comment: yes I have got valid JSON ffrom server, i have rechecked and applied resp.json() just after recieving response,

Comment: I agree with @GarrettMcCullough, you probably need to just do `dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(JSON.parse(facultyMembers))` in your state.

Comment: ohh yes Thnx alot sir you both, i think i didnt understand what actually happend, am I getting string not json? at server end m using objectmapper.writeValueAsString(hashmap)... if you can lil bit explain it @MattAft

Comment: The function name, `writeValueAsString` makes is sound like the server is sending a string.  The result of the ListView looks like it's getting a string.  So I would say either you're not parsing the string to JSON or maybe you're not storing the JSON and you're storing the string by mistake.  It's hard to know without knowing what `SessionManager.getSessionValue` is doing.  I can't find that library/function so I'm guessing it's custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @MattAft and @Garrett McCullough, I was not parsing the string back to JSON as I was expecting I already getting the JSON

hence this simple solution works

```
ds.cloneWithRows(JSON.parse(facultyMembers))
```